# Sharing internet through USB adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have a notebook with WiFi port and main computer which connects to the internet through dsl cable modem.  I bought wireless usb adapter (dwa-125) and though I could share internet connection of my main computer through that adapter.

Now it seems to me that I am wrong.  Adapters don't seem to be able to see each other.  What are my options?

Do i have to by some additional hardware?

Comment: Ok, this one will take a few step by step instructions.  I'll need to know what versions of windows you're running on the desktop and laptop, please specify which one is on each.  Also, is the wireless adapter properly installed?

Comment: I use Win7 as a desktop computer (XP is also available) and I have lenovo notebook which hosts Win7 as well.

Comment: Don't I need access point as well?  Or my adapter does can receive requests from laptop's WiFi port?

Comment: Have you tried the "Quick Adapter Setup Installation Wizard CD-ROM" that comes iwth the [D-Link DWA-125](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=722)?

Comment: I only see driver installation tab (besides other useless tabs).  I just doubt that you can connect to computers with WiFi ports theoretically, although you can do that with LAN cables.

Comment: Actually I am able to create a RECORD about wireless connection.  That is, to fill in fields in setup dialog box.  But, so what - notebook does not see it any way.